# EF Core - How to Include collection for item in included collection

Tags: c#, nested, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have **Request** class, which has two collections (**Details** and **RequestHistoryRecords**). Detail in Details collection also have **DetailHistoryRecords** collection.

I would like to delete the whole request with all referenced collections (by foreaching all items and delete them one by one). But I have issue to load all the collections at once.

**classes**

```
public class Request
{
   public IList<Detail> Details { get; private set; } = new List<Detail>();
   public IList<RequestHistory> RequestHistoryRecords { get; private set; } = new List<RequestHistory>();
}

public class Detail
{
   public IList<DetailHistory> DetailHistoryRecords { get; private set; } = new List<DetailHistory>();
}
```

**db context definition**

```
// 1-n relationship
 modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
     .HasMany(x => x.Details)
     .WithOne();

 // 1-n relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
     .HasMany(x => x.RequestHistoryRecords)
     .WithOne();

// 1-n relationship
modelBuilder.Entity<Detail>()
      .HasMany(x => x.DetailHistoryRecords)
      .WithOne();
```

I tried to load all the collections with `Include` and `ThenInclude` method, but I do not see **DetailHistoryRecords** collection, I don't know why. Am I on the right track or should I do the loading completely differently ?

```
var request = _context.Request
        .Include(x => x.Details) // Works
        .ThenInclude(details => details./*I do not see DetailHistoryRecords here ?! */)
        .Include(x => x.RequestHistoryRecords) // Works
        .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

AS I can see Details and RequestHistoryRecords are not  depend on each other. you can remove below line in query.

```
.ThenInclude(details => details./*I do not see DetailHistoryRecords here ?! */)
```

Call below code

```
var request = _context.Request
        .Include(x => x.Details) // Works
        .Include(x => x.RequestHistoryRecords) // Works
        .Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: In that case, **Detail.DetailHistoryRecords** has count 0, but in database there is one record.

Comment: yes. but in the last you are  adding condition which matches "id",So this tell that the record in Details and DetailHistoryRecords having id=some id.If that doest match ,it will return null. try to look value in Db with that Id is present or not.

Comment: The **DetailHistoryRecords** has `RequestId` same as `Request.Id` and also `DetailId` is the same as `Detail.Id` so the values in the database are correct. But only issue is that the data are not loaded to `Detail.DetailHistoryRecords` collection. So the question is how should I load the collection ?

Comment: the count is 0 probably because of constructor initialization `new List<DetailHistory>();` otherwise it would be `null`

Comment: Use new lambda object y  like .Include(y => y.RequestHistoryRecords) // Works

Comment: I tried, but it does not helped. I do not have issue with `RequestHistoryRecords`, I have empty different collection named `DetailHistoryRecords`.